# Last day of month aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to get an Elasticsearch date histogram aggregation of a sumarized value by the last day of each month:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "lang":   "painless",
              "source": "doc['my_date'].value.getDayOfMonth() == params.day1",
              "params": {
                  "day1": 7
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ...
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "value_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "my_date",
        "calendar_interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_by_month": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that some months the day "7" is weekend, on a yearly report I get some empty values.
**value** is a growing number that receives a small income every day, I just want to sumarize every **wallet** that I have by month on a yearly report.

Is there a way to get the last week day of a month on a elastic search aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to recreate indexes by saving only the last valid day of a month, moving the logic to the ETL instead of elastic. The good thing about it is that I don't need the painless script anymore, and the search is way faster.